# Escape column name in query (to avoid conflict with reserved words)

Tags: google-sheets, escaping, google-sheets-query

I have a Google Sheets and want to query in a column called `BY`. This is failing:

```
=query(Data!A:GC, "select BY where BG = 'completed'")
```

How can I escape that `BY` column name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try [backquotes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) - eg:

```
=query(Data!A:GC, "select `BY` where BG = 'completed'")
```

Answer (score 0):

so to use the column BY as an identifier you must use backquotes around it...

```
`BY`
```

CREDIT: JAMES @ https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/tFB_02gNceQ/-2IUvmnQBgAJ